# Dealing with jQuery conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prestashop

I'm coding a website under Prestashop and I'm experiencing trouble with jQuery, Bootstrap and some Prestashop modules (such as Advanced Search 4).

If I include the jQuery line, jQuery functions in Advanced Search's js won't work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But if I do not include the jQuery line, I get the 'Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery' error.

It's clearly a conflict between Bootstrap and Advanced Search versions of jQuery, but I don't know how to cope with this... Any clue ?

(here's the website: [toiles-de-mayenne.com](https://toiles-de-mayenne.com))

Comment: Could it be because you're using the minimal jQuery?

Comment: But jQuery is included by default by PrestaShop. Why do you need to include it again? Are you attaching your JS files before jQuery library?

Comment: You can just use jQuery's [noConflict method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), which means after including new jQuery, just do: `$.noConflict(); jQuery( document ).ready(function($) { .... });`

Comment: Thanks @skobaljic, I think it did the job :)